# Rerender parent Page block while closing child

Tags: rerender

I have two VF page and trying to mimic somewhat send an email functionality. I have add attachment button and it opens a child pop up to upload the document. While closing this popup, I want to refresh the specific output panel of parent page using apex:actionfunction. This is not happening. Here is the complete code for the same

Parent Controller class

```
public class ClsSendEmailByTemplate{
    public Id propertyId{get;set;}
   private final Lead propertyInstance {get;set;}
    @TestVisible public List<wrapper_SelectedImages> wrapList {get; set;}
    public Integer rowToRemove {get;set;}
    @TestVisible public List<WrapperDocument> DocumentList{get; set;}
     public Map<Id, String> selectedAttachment {get; set;}
     Id UsrId;
     public String  Keywords {get; set;}
    public string EmailTempateId{get;set;}
    public EmailTemplate ET{get;set;}
    public string emailVal{get;set;}
    public string cc{get;set;}
    public string emailSubject{get;set;}
    public string body{get;set;}
    public User usr{get;set;}
    public Contact CT{get;set;}
  public Lead LD{get;set;}
 //public List<WrapperDocument> DocumentsList{get; set;}

    public ClsSendEmailByTemplate(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
           propertyId =  controller.getId();
           UsrId= UserInfo.getUserId();
           Keywords = Datetime.now().format('mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS');
           propertyInstance = [SELECT id,Name FROM Lead WHERE Id=:propertyId LIMIT 1];
          usr = new User();
          ct = new Contact();
          LD = new Lead();
    }
    public void getTemplate(){
        try{
            if(EmailTempateId == null || EmailTempateId == ''){
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please Select Email Template'));
            }
            else{
                ET = [Select Id,Subject,Body from EmailTemplate where Id =: EmailTempateId];
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }
        public List<wrapper_SelectedImages> getwrapperList(){
        System.debug('=='+propertyId);
        if(wrapList == null){
            wrapList = new List<wrapper_SelectedImages>();

            for(Attachment attachItr : [SELECT id,parentId, Name, CreatedById,   body, ContentType,CreatedDate from Attachment WHERE ParentId=: propertyId ]){
                wrapList.add(new wrapper_SelectedImages(attachItr.id, attachItr.Name,attachItr.Body, attachItr.ContentType ));
            }
      }
       return wrapList;
    }

    public pageReference getDocuments()

    {

      getDocList();



      return null;



    } 
     public List<WrapperDocument> getDocList(){

        if(DocumentList== null){
            DocumentList= new List<WrapperDocument>();

            for(Document DocumentItr : [SELECT id , Name, CreatedById,   body, ContentType,CreatedDate from Document where folderid =:UsrId   ]){
                DocumentList.add(new WrapperDocument(DocumentItr.id, DocumentItr.Name,DocumentItr.Body, DocumentItr.ContentType ));
            }
      }
        return DocumentList;
    }


     public void SendMail( ){
        try{ 
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            if (ET.Id <> Null)
            {    email.setTemplateId(ET.Id);   
            } 

            Contact con = new Contact();
            con.FirstName = 'Test';
            con.LastName = 'Contact';
            con.Email = 'anoop@gnxtsystems.com';
            insert con;
            email.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] sendResult;
           // List<Attachment> attachments= [SELECT id,parentId, Name, body, ContentType,CreatedById, CreatedDate from Attachment WHERE ParentId=: propertyId ];
            List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> emailAttachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
for(wrapper_SelectedImages att : wrapList ) {

if (att.isSelected == true)
{
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    // You may need to do some work here to figure out the correct file extension
    efa.setFileName(att.Name);
    // Take the blob data from the Attachment and put it on the email.
    efa.setBody(att.Body);
    efa.setContentType(att.ContentType);
    emailAttachments.add(efa);
    }
    email.setFileAttachments(emailAttachments);

}

            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r =Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Email Has Been Sent');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }

      @TestVisible public Class wrapper_SelectedImages{
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        public Id wrapAttachfileId {get;set;}
        public String name {get; set;}
        public String OwnerId{get; set;}
        public String ContentType{get; set;}
        public BLOB Body{get; set;}
        Public String CreatedDate{get; set;}
        Public String CreatedById{get; set;}
        public wrapper_SelectedImages(Id attachfileId, String Name, blob body, string contenttype){
            this.isSelected = false;
            this.wrapAttachfileId = attachfileId;
            this.name = Name;
            this.Body = body;
            this.ContentType=contenttype;
        }
    }
    public void removeRowFromAccList(){
          DocumentList=  removeRowToDocList(rowToRemove, DocumentList);

 }
     public static List<WrapperDocument> removeRowToDocList(Integer rowToRemove, List<WrapperDocument> DocumentList){
        DocumentList.remove(rowToRemove);
        return DocumentList;
    }
    @TestVisible public Class WrapperDocument{
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        public Id wrapAttachfileId {get;set;}
        public String name {get; set;}
        public String OwnerId{get; set;}
        public String ContentType{get; set;}
        public String Keywords{get; set;}

        public BLOB Body{get; set;}
        Public String CreatedDate{get; set;}
        Public String CreatedById{get; set;}
        public WrapperDocument(Id attachfileId, String Name, blob body, string contenttype){
            this.isSelected = false;
            this.wrapAttachfileId = attachfileId;
            this.name = Name;
            this.Body = body;
            this.ContentType=contenttype;
        }
    }
}
```

Parent VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="ClsSendEmailByTemplate" showChat="false" showheader="true" sidebar="true" standardStylesheets="true">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Lead" subtitle="Send an email"/>
  <style>
            .bPageBlock .detailList .dataCol {
             width: 0;

            }
            #TD 
            {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
        </style>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:pageBlock id="PB">

    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                  <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!sendMail}"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Add Attachments"  onClick="OpenDocumentUploadPOPUP();" id="addAttachment"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Select Email Template" onclick="OpenSelectTempatePOPUP();" id="theButton" />
                  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">


            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

             <apex:outputLabel value="Lead"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ct.OwnerId}" required="false" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Contact"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!usr.ContactID}" />    
             </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
               <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Additional To:" /> 
                   <apex:inputTextArea id="AdditionalemailInput"     style="width:500px"/>
               </apex:pageblockSectionItem>  

                 <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="CC:" /> 
                   <apex:inputTextArea id="AdditionalCCemailInput"     style="width:500px"/>
               </apex:pageblockSectionItem>          
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Subject" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!ET.Subject}" style="width: 500px;"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Body" />
                <apex:inputTextarea style="height:300px; width:1020px" value="{!ET.Body}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>      

     </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlock title="Notes & Attachments">

                 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wl">

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wl.isSelected }"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Title">
                        <a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!wl.wrapAttachfileId}" target="_blank"><apex:outputLabel >{!wl.name}</apex:outputLabel></a>
                    </apex:column>

                   </apex:pageBlockTable>


            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:actionFunction name="callBackFunction" reRender="EmailAttachments" action ="{!getDocuments}"/>

   <apex:outputPanel id="EmailAttachments">

             <apex:pageBlock title="Email Attachments">

  <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>  
                 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!DocList}" var="dl">
                <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:commandLink value="Remove" style="color:red" action="{!removeRowFromAccList}" rendered="{!rowNum > 0}" rerender="EmailAttachments" immediate="true" >
             <apex:param value="{!rowNum-1}" name="rowToRemove" assignTo="{!rowToRemove}"/>
         </apex:commandLink>
         <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum +1 }"/>
      </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Title">
                        <a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!dl.wrapAttachfileId}" target="_blank"><apex:outputLabel >{!dl.name}</apex:outputLabel></a>
                    </apex:column>

                   </apex:pageBlockTable>


            </apex:pageBlock> </apex:outputPanel> 
    <apex:actionfunction name="getTemplate" action="{!getTemplate}" reRender="PB">
        <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!EmailTempateId}" name="val"/>
    </apex:actionfunction>
</apex:form>

<script>
    function OpenSelectTempatePOPUP(){
        window.open('/apex/SelectTemplate','Ratting','width=1200,height=620,toolbar=0,menubar=0,status=1,resizable=0');
        return false;
    }

     function OpenDocumentUploadPOPUP(){
        window.open('/apex/DocumentUpload?val={!Keywords}','Ratting','width=400,height=400,toolbar=0,menubar=0,status=0,resizable=0');
        return false;
    }
    function calldisplaytemplate(id){
        getTemplate(id);
    }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Child Controller

```
public with sharing class FileUploadController {


      public Document document {
        get {

          if (document == null)
            document = new Document();

          return document;
        }

        set;

      }


      public PageReference upload() {


        document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        document.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(); // put it in running user's folder
        document.Keywords =  apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('val');

        try {
          insert document;
        } catch (DMLException e) {

          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));
          return null;

        } finally {

          document.body = null; // clears the viewstate
          document = new Document();

        }


        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'File uploaded successfully'));

        return null;

      }



    }
```

Child VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="FileUploadController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" id="page">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function closeWin(){    

            parent.window.opener.callBackFunction();  

            window.top.close();  

    }
    function closeWindow_NoAction(){
        window.close();
    }
</script>



        <apex:sectionHeader title="Visualforce Example" subtitle="Add Attachment"/>


      <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <apex:pageMessages />

        <apex:pageBlock title="Upload a File">



          <apex:pageBlockButtons >

            <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Save"/>
           <apex:commandButton value="Close" onclick="closeWin();"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>



          <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">






            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

              <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>

              <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}" id="file"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>











      </apex:pageBlock>

      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: that's a lot of code man:) Probably you should remove some so that your post is readable...

Comment: ... and so `parent.window.opener.callBackFunction();` stands out.